# notepad++ Weird things since latest update

Tags: newline

- If im typing a normal text and press `Enter` for new line it auto types `True` or  `( , , , , ,  )` or sometimes `()`,
- So its impossible to even type a normal text cause i have to go back and edit away these weird lines.
- How would one fix this?

edit2: new example of random input "( , , , , , , , , , 2.71828182845905 )"

Comment: you must google about this, this site is basically meant for development issues not for text editor problems....

Answer (score 0):

Preferences=>Auto-completion?  IF Enabled, Disable and try again.

Comment: Make sure Enter is not re-defined.  You have 2 enter key, both do the same?

Comment: Yes both give these weird parenthesis and numbers however it seems to only happen on lines that contains a comma

Comment: Under Run, Check your "Shortcut Mapper".  Especially Scintilla commands, ENTER should be SCI_NEWLINE

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, apparently NppCalc plugin caused this.